# Could Issues Occur Using a Singleton SQLConnection in a Single User .NET Desktop Application?

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, connection-pooling, sqlconnection

I have inherited a .NET desktop application and am trying to track down an intermittant bug where database locks are not being released.

The application takes a Singleton approach to establishing a `SQLConnection` and I'm wondering if creating and holding open a single instance of a `SQLConnection` in memory could cause issues in this context?

**I know connection pooling makes this code redundant**. What I want to know is: given my scenario of each instance of a single-threaded desktop application having a single user, *could* this approach causes issues?

```
private static SqlConnection connection;

public static SqlConnection Connection
{
    get
    {
        if (connection == null) {
            connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "...";
            connection.Open();
        }
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
            connection.Open();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

**Edit #1**: I know this is not best practice; I know connections should be opened late and closed early; I know connection pooling makes this code redundant. In my specific instance, is an issue demonstrable?

Comment: I would say that this depends on how the singleton is being used. There could be some cases where the consuming methods might do something like:

`var conn = SqlConnection.Connection;` In this case, they will get the initially open connection, but something could happen to close it. Then when they try to reuse `conn` they will get a connection error.

Comment: @EricMagers Given the code as it is, even if someone were to assign the connection to a local variable and/or call close on it directly, `Connection` would notice it on the next access attempt and reopen the connection. I'm not seeing issues with connection errors where connections have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old and obsolete design which is now deprecated in favor of keeping the connectiuon open as little as possible and close and dispose it immediately after each usage witha  using clause,

said that the pattern you have shown above should not, only because of itself, create database locks,

consider that even with a connection kept open longer time the connection itself is only a channel so most of the thing depends on the way you use it with Command and Reader objects which when possible you should anyway close and dispose as soon as no longer needed.

If there are some tables locked in the database are you sur ethat is not happening because of multiple users trying to access the same objects at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Singleton for a SqlConnection object is a really, really bad idea. There is no reason to do this whatsoever.

If you are attempting to avoid a performance hit of "new SqlConnection()" or "connection.Open()" be advised that there really is no performance hit there because of the connection pooling going on behind the scenes. Connection Pooling handles the opening/closing of the expensive connections. Not the SqlConnection object.

**You won't be able to open multiple SqlDataReaders/Commands with the connection at the same time and will run into thread blocking issues if you are trying to share the same connection object with multiple threads.**

The Singleton pattern is the most over used and abused pattern and there are many side effects of the singleton that you may not be aware of. Very good talk about the dangers of singletons here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI

Comment: I understand how connection pooling works with SQLConnection and I understand current best practice and the dangers of singletons. The application in question is a single-threaded, single user desktop application. What I want to know is __could__ this code causes issues?

Comment: If you do a BEGIN TRANSACTION and there's an error or something else happens where your code doesn't hit a COMMIT or ROLLBACK, then you leave that transaction open. As long as you don't COMMIT or ROLLBACK a transaction, it's still "running" and potentially holding locks.